# Programmatically Download Embedded SWFs from Sites?

Tags: ruby, download, flash

This is probably considered hacking, but is it possible to programmatically download swfs using something like Ruby?  Not decompiling them, just downloading them so I can view them without having to go to the site with a billion advertisements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the address of the flash movie:

```
require 'net/http'

Net::HTTP.start( 'www.example.com' ) { |http|
  resp = http.get( '/movie.swf' )
  open( '/tmp/movie.swf', 'wb' ) { |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a very straightforward URL download as long as the site isn't doing something to prevent people from doing this, e.g. checking the REFERER field or a cookie.

There are a number of browser plugins (FF must have a dozen of them) that facilitate this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

you may think this is silly!! open up a text browser like elinks and load a page which has swf file/content, then it'll only ask what to do and downloads content, has worked for me.......